# Calculate average revenue per user over time with cancellation rates factored in

Tags: calculus, statistics

I'm hoping the best brains can help me out here with a equation that calculates how much revenue I can expect per user over time.

The input values are as follows.
I provide a service that have $1000$ users that pays $10$ per month. Think similar to Spotify.
Each month $3$ percent or $30$ of the users cancels the service and stops paying. But each month $30$ new users sign up and pays me $10$ so the net income and user base is the same.
If a customer have been part of the service for $60$ months, it will automatically cancel.

Out of the percent that cancels, some will have been a paying customer for only $1$ month, meaning the revenue of that user is $10\cdot 1$, and some would have been a customer for $60$ months, so their revenue is going to be $10 \cdot 60$.

I'm looking for an equation that will simulate on average how many months these $30$ customers that sign up will be a paying customer, basically how many months of revenue can I expect per user given the input values above. Like for example on average each customer that signs up this month will stay for $27$ months, so the revenue will be $27\cdot 10$.

As a next step I wanna see different outcomes if cancellation rates goes to 2 or 4 percent and if new customer sign up per month is higher than cancellations, but as a first step getting the basic equation in place.

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: No answers... is this complicated? I thought a math genius would solve it in 30 secs based on the other equations posted here?